# Java Collection HashSet vs HashMap

Tags: java, memory, collections, hashmap, hashset

I have Question regarding the best practice of using a `Collection` regarding the memory. I need to call a method which returns pairs of (Key,Value) frequently, so which way is the best, using `HashMap` or creating an Object that contains Key and value and save this object in a `HashSet`?

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: The answer to "which data structure should I use" is always "depends what you need to do with it". Can you elaborate on your needs?

Comment: Please refer this tutorial, hope it will help you better. http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/

Comment: Both approaches have their uses, and it may depend on whether the key is conceptually a "part" of the value (HashSet) or independent of it (HashMap).

Comment: Thanks All, My need is save the key and values without duplication, and the objects which saved up-to 10 objects per method call, but the calling will be frequently 1 per second, so I want to use the way which consume less for memory.

Comment: @Hazim - You are going to need to be more precise and specific than that.

Comment: A `HashSet` is a thin wrapper *around* a `HashMap` (look at the source code, search for `private transient HashMap<E,Object> map`) so theoretically, `HashMap` consumes less memory. But the overhead is minimal.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether you need to search the data structure based on the key alone or both the key and the value.

- If you search by the key alone (i.e. `map.containsKey(key)`), you should use a `HashMap`.
- If you search for existence of a key-value pair (i.e. `set.contains(new Pair(key,value)`), you should use a `HashSet` that contains those pairs.

Another thing to consider is how you determine the uniqueness of the elements. If it is determined by the key alone, you should use a `HashMap`. If it is determined by both key and value (i.e. you can have the same key appear twice with different values), you must use `HashSet`, since `HashhMap` doesn't allow the same key to appear more than once.

Comment: you can also add some special functionality to your "key value" object if needed

Comment: Thanks All, My need is save the key and values without duplication, and the objects which saved up-to 10 objects per method call, but the calling will be frequently 1 per second, so I want to use the way which consume less for memory.

Comment: @Hazim But how are you going to access this data structure? Are you going to iterate over the entire data, or search for the existence of specific values? And do you allow the same key to appear twice with different values?

Comment: i iterate the key value, no need to search only save object and iterator. i already override the hashcode of keyvalue class to prevent the duplication

Comment: @Hazim Based on your comment, I can assume that your collection needs to allow the same key to appear twice for different values, and therefore you must use `HashSet<keyvalue>`, and can't use `HashMap<key,value>`.